# Image 100% of parent. Parent is position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Could somebody please assist. I am trying get an image to have a `max-height` and an `auto` width. The problem is these rules are being ignored as it's parent is `fixed`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/gop4jhm9/5/

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 30%;
}

#myDiv img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%; // being ignored
}
```

Is there any way of doing this via CSS, JS, jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the `#myDiv` with two `max-height` attributes. Take away the second one, which restricts the div to 30%, and it will work in fixed.

Comment: but i dont' want the div going larger than the page, therefore it need a max height??

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. How large do you want the div? `max-height:100%` won't make it larger than the page.

Comment: Hold on I got it. Please hold.

Comment: See Freijlord's answer.

Comment: @freijlord s anser sets a blanket height of `90%` to the image. I need the behaviour of `max-height`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into Bootstrap, or at least some kind of responsive framework. If I'm understanding your problem, you want the parent div to resize based on the child object (image in this case), and the image to resize based on the screen?

Comment: I'm not going to adopt an entire framework for this one issue. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That is because it intends to keep the image's aspect ratio because you set the margin to auto. if you wish for a max height to be set, set it in the `max-height` property of the `#myDiv.img`.

```
#myDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#myDiv.img
{
     width: auto;
     max-height:90%;
}
```

Comment: I did try this. I used 30% as an example but basically I need the div to be auto height/width depending on the image, but with a max height of `90%`  so then the whole thing displays on smaller screen;

Comment: Then you should set the `height` property to 90%.

Comment: By doing that I am not allowing auto height. This will result in everything being stretched on larger screens. I need a `max-height` of 90%, not a set height of `90%`